# Devops with Xamarin and hockeyapp

Tags: xamarin, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, hockeyapp

We are trying to implement devops with xamarin and hockeyapp. Basically we would like to automate the build process for all platforms(iOS,Android and Windows). When we have searched for this we can see that it goes with continuous delivery and integration. Means the build will be automatically pushed to HockeyApp after code checked in.

However, can we go in other way instead of CI/CD? Like through power shell script to automate the deployment.
How can we do this from VSTS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Jenkins](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/) for that, it has a [Hockeyapp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HockeyApp+Plugin) that allows you to upload your build to your users.

Here is a quick article about that: https://blog.entelect.co.za/view/9973/using-hockey-app-with-jenkins-for-continuous-mobile-app-deployment

Comment: Can we do anything from VSTS ?

Comment: Yes, I found the Hockeyapp extension also for VSTS ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.hockeyapp#overview )